# como selecciono y doy click en "Seleccione la comuna" que aparece en la imagen con selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium

Necesito dar click en una lista de comunas. He intentado llegar y dar click en la lista pero no encuentro el xpath correcto. Intente con este:
comu = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='ng-binding ng-scope'] and text()='ALTO BIOBIO')
comu.click()

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<tbody>
            <tr>
                    <th class="field-label col-md-3">Comuna</th> 
                    <td class="col-md-3 mitad" ng-class="{'has-error':(form.Comuna.$invalid &amp;&amp; form.$submitted)}">
                        <div class="ui-select-container ui-select-bootstrap dropdown ng-touched ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required open" ng-class="{open: $select.open}" ng-disabled="vm.setEstatus != 'modificar'" ng-model="vm.comuna" theme="bootstrap" name="Comuna" focus-on="Comuna" required="required" ng-change="vm.buscarPredioDireccion(); vm.buscarMontoMaximoAvaluoByComuna()" mensaje-error="Debe seleccionar una comuna" style=""><div class="ui-select-match ng-scope ng-hide" ng-hide="$select.open &amp;&amp; $select.searchEnabled" ng-disabled="$select.disabled" ng-class="{'btn-default-focus':$select.focus}" placeholder="Seleccione la comuna" style=""><span tabindex="-1" class="btn btn-default form-control ui-select-toggle" aria-label="Select box activate" ng-disabled="$select.disabled" ng-click="$select.activate()" style="outline: 0;"><span ng-show="$select.isEmpty()" class="ui-select-placeholder text-muted ng-binding ng-hide" style="">Seleccione la comuna</span> <span ng-hide="$select.isEmpty()" class="ui-select-match-text pull-left" ng-class="{'ui-select-allow-clear': $select.allowClear &amp;&amp; !$select.isEmpty()}" ng-transclude="" style=""><span class="ng-binding ng-scope">SANTIAGO
                            </span></span> <i class="caret pull-right" ng-click="$select.toggle($event)"></i> <a ng-show="$select.allowClear &amp;&amp; !$select.isEmpty() &amp;&amp; ($select.disabled !== true)" aria-label="Select box clear" style="margin-right: 10px" ng-click="$select.clear($event)" class="btn btn-xs btn-link pull-right ng-hide"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></span></div><span ng-show="$select.open &amp;&amp; $select.refreshing &amp;&amp; $select.spinnerEnabled" class="ui-select-refreshing glyphicon glyphicon-refresh ui-select-spin ng-hide"></span> <input type="search" autocomplete="off" tabindex="-1" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Select box" aria-owns="ui-select-choices-4" class="form-control ui-select-search ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched" ng-class="{ 'ui-select-search-hidden' : !$select.searchEnabled }" placeholder="Seleccione la comuna" ng-model="$select.search" ng-show="$select.open" style="width: 211px;"><ul class="ui-select-choices ui-select-choices-content ui-select-dropdown dropdown-menu ng-scope" ng-show="$select.open &amp;&amp; $select.items.length > 0" repeat="item in vm.comunas | filter: $select.search" style="opacity: 1;"><li class="ui-select-choices-group" id="ui-select-choices-4"><div class="divider ng-hide" ng-show="$select.isGrouped &amp;&amp; $index > 0"></div><div ng-show="$select.isGrouped" class="ui-select-choices-group-label dropdown-header ng-binding ng-hide" ng-bind="$group.name"></div><!-- ngRepeat: item in $select.items --><!-- ngIf: $select.open --><div ng-attr-id="ui-select-choices-row-{{ $select.generatedId }}-{{$index}}" class="ui-select-choices-row ng-scope" ng-class="{active: $select.isActive(this), disabled: $select.isDisabled(this)}" role="option" ng-repeat="item in $select.items" ng-if="$select.open" ng-click="$select.select(item,$select.skipFocusser,$event)" id="ui-select-choices-row-4-0" style=""><span class="ui-select-choices-row-inner" uis-transclude-append="">
                                <span ng-bind-html="item.nombre | highlight: $select.search" class="ng-binding ng-scope">ALGARROBO</span>
                            </span></div><!-- end ngIf: $select.open --><!-- end ngRepeat: item in $select.items --><!-- ngIf: $select.open --><div ng-attr-id="ui-select-choices-row-{{ $select.generatedId }}-{{$index}}" class="ui-select-choices-row ng-scope" ng-class="{active: $select.isActive(this), disabled: $select.isDisabled(this)}" role="option" ng-repeat="item in $select.items" ng-if="$select.open" ng-click="$select.select(item,$select.skipFocusser,$event)" id="ui-select-choices-row-4-1"><span class="ui-select-choices-row-inner" uis-transclude-append="">
                                <span ng-bind-html="item.nombre | highlight: $select.search" class="ng-binding ng-scope">ALHUE</span>
                            </span></div><!-- end ngIf: $select.open --><!-- end ngRepeat: item in $select.items --><!-- ngIf: $select.open --><div ng-attr-id="ui-select-choices-row-{{ $select.generatedId }}-{{$index}}" class="ui-select-choices-row ng-scope" ng-class="{active: $select.isActive(this), disabled: $select.isDisabled(this)}" role="option" ng-repeat="item in $select.items" ng-if="$select.open" ng-click="$select.select(item,$select.skipFocusser,$event)" id="ui-select-choices-row-4-2"><span class="ui-select-choices-row-inner" uis-transclude-append="">
                                <span ng-bind-html="item.nombre | highlight: $select.search" class="ng-binding ng-scope">ALTO BIOBIO</span>
                            </span></div><!-- end ngIf: $select.open --><!-- end ngRepeat: item in $select.items --><!-- ngIf: $select.open --><div ng-attr-id="ui-select-choices-row-{{ $select.generatedId }}-{{$index}}" class="ui-select-choices-row ng-scope" ng-class="{active: $select.isActive(this), disabled: $select.isDisabled(this)}" role="option" ng-repeat="item in $select.items" ng-if="$select.open" ng-click="$select.select(item,$select.skipFocusser,$event)" id="ui-select-choices-row-4-3"><span class="ui-select-choices-row-inner" uis-transclude-append="">
                                <span ng-bind-html="item.nombre | highlight: $select.search" class="ng-binding ng-scope">ALTO DEL CARMEN</span>
                            
                            </span></div><!-- end ngIf: $select.open --><!-- end ngRepeat: item in $select.items --></li></ul><div class="ui-select-no-choice"></div><ui-select-single></ui-select-single><input ng-disabled="$select.disabled" class="ui-select-focusser ui-select-offscreen ng-scope" type="text" id="focusser-4" aria-label="Select box focus" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" disabled=""></div>
                    </td>
                    
            </tr>

</tbody>
```

Comment: Hola @rickhuntertable, puedes mostrar el código de html completo para poder visualizar qué es lo que falta y poder ayudarte?

Comment: hola. gracias. Ya logré llegar a la etiqueta, pero ahora me indica "ttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'". En esta linea: comu = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='ng-binding ng-scope']"). Es cuando intento escribir o dar click con "comu.click()" o "comu.send_keys". Como puedo escribir en esa etiqueta?.

Answer (score 0):

El siguiente XPath funciona bien:

```
//span[@class='ng-binding ng-scope' and contains(text(), 'ALTO BIOBIO')]
```

Puedes leer más sobre las funciones de String de XPath en este link: https://devhints.io/xpath#string-functions

Comment: Por favor, proporciona detalles adicionales en tu respuesta. Tal como está escrita actualmente, es difícil entender tu solución.

Answer (score -1):

No he logrado encontrar el xpath y seleccionar la comuna. Adjunto extracto del código de la pagina. Por ejemplo si quiero a traves de un parametro seleccionar la comuna de ALTO BIOBIO ("ALTO BIOBIO"). Como se debería hacer con XPATH.
ejemplo: comu = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='ng-binding ng-scope'] and [text() ='ALTO BIOBIO']")

```
<tbody>
        <tr>
                <th class="field-label col-md-3">Comuna</th> 
                <td class="col-md-3 mitad" ng-class="{'has-error':(form.Comuna.$invalid &amp;&amp; form.$submitted)}">
                    <div class="ui-select-container ui-select-bootstrap dropdown ng-touched ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required open" ng-class="{open: $select.open}" ng-disabled="vm.setEstatus != 'modificar'" ng-model="vm.comuna" theme="bootstrap" name="Comuna" focus-on="Comuna" required="required" ng-change="vm.buscarPredioDireccion(); vm.buscarMontoMaximoAvaluoByComuna()" mensaje-error="Debe seleccionar una comuna" style=""><div class="ui-select-match ng-scope ng-hide" ng-hide="$select.open &amp;&amp; $select.searchEnabled" ng-disabled="$select.disabled" ng-class="{'btn-default-focus':$select.focus}" placeholder="Seleccione la comuna" style=""><span tabindex="-1" class="btn btn-default form-control ui-select-toggle" aria-label="Select box activate" ng-disabled="$select.disabled" ng-click="$select.activate()" style="outline: 0;"><span ng-show="$select.isEmpty()" class="ui-select-placeholder text-muted ng-binding ng-hide" style="">Seleccione la comuna</span> <span ng-hide="$select.isEmpty()" class="ui-select-match-text pull-left" ng-class="{'ui-select-allow-clear': $select.allowClear &amp;&amp; !$select.isEmpty()}" ng-transclude="" style=""><span class="ng-binding ng-scope">SANTIAGO
                        </span></span> <i class="caret pull-right" ng-click="$select.toggle($event)"></i> <a ng-show="$select.allowClear &amp;&amp; !$select.isEmpty() &amp;&amp; ($select.disabled !== true)" aria-label="Select box clear" style="margin-right: 10px" ng-click="$select.clear($event)" class="btn btn-xs btn-link pull-right ng-hide"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></span></div><span ng-show="$select.open &amp;&amp; $select.refreshing &amp;&amp; $select.spinnerEnabled" class="ui-select-refreshing glyphicon glyphicon-refresh ui-select-spin ng-hide"></span> <input type="search" autocomplete="off" tabindex="-1" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Select box" aria-owns="ui-select-choices-4" class="form-control ui-select-search ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched" ng-class="{ 'ui-select-search-hidden' : !$select.searchEnabled }" placeholder="Seleccione la comuna" ng-model="$select.search" ng-show="$select.open" style="width: 211px;"><ul class="ui-select-choices ui-select-choices-content ui-select-dropdown dropdown-menu ng-scope" ng-show="$select.open &amp;&amp; $select.items.length > 0" repeat="item in vm.comunas | filter: $select.search" style="opacity: 1;"><li class="ui-select-choices-group" id="ui-select-choices-4"><div class="divider ng-hide" ng-show="$select.isGrouped &amp;&amp; $index > 0"></div><div ng-show="$select.isGrouped" class="ui-select-choices-group-label dropdown-header ng-binding ng-hide" ng-bind="$group.name"></div><!-- ngRepeat: item in $select.items --><!-- ngIf: $select.open --><div ng-attr-id="ui-select-choices-row-{{ $select.generatedId }}-{{$index}}" class="ui-select-choices-row ng-scope" ng-class="{active: $select.isActive(this), disabled: $select.isDisabled(this)}" role="option" ng-repeat="item in $select.items" ng-if="$select.open" ng-click="$select.select(item,$select.skipFocusser,$event)" id="ui-select-choices-row-4-0" style=""><span class="ui-select-choices-row-inner" uis-transclude-append="">
                            <span ng-bind-html="item.nombre | highlight: $select.search" class="ng-binding ng-scope">ALGARROBO</span>
                        </span></div><!-- end ngIf: $select.open --><!-- end ngRepeat: item in $select.items --><!-- ngIf: $select.open --><div ng-attr-id="ui-select-choices-row-{{ $select.generatedId }}-{{$index}}" class="ui-select-choices-row ng-scope" ng-class="{active: $select.isActive(this), disabled: $select.isDisabled(this)}" role="option" ng-repeat="item in $select.items" ng-if="$select.open" ng-click="$select.select(item,$select.skipFocusser,$event)" id="ui-select-choices-row-4-1"><span class="ui-select-choices-row-inner" uis-transclude-append="">
                            <span ng-bind-html="item.nombre | highlight: $select.search" class="ng-binding ng-scope">ALHUE</span>
                        </span></div><!-- end ngIf: $select.open --><!-- end ngRepeat: item in $select.items --><!-- ngIf: $select.open --><div ng-attr-id="ui-select-choices-row-{{ $select.generatedId }}-{{$index}}" class="ui-select-choices-row ng-scope" ng-class="{active: $select.isActive(this), disabled: $select.isDisabled(this)}" role="option" ng-repeat="item in $select.items" ng-if="$select.open" ng-click="$select.select(item,$select.skipFocusser,$event)" id="ui-select-choices-row-4-2"><span class="ui-select-choices-row-inner" uis-transclude-append="">
                            <span ng-bind-html="item.nombre | highlight: $select.search" class="ng-binding ng-scope">ALTO BIOBIO</span>
                        </span></div><!-- end ngIf: $select.open --><!-- end ngRepeat: item in $select.items --><!-- ngIf: $select.open --><div ng-attr-id="ui-select-choices-row-{{ $select.generatedId }}-{{$index}}" class="ui-select-choices-row ng-scope" ng-class="{active: $select.isActive(this), disabled: $select.isDisabled(this)}" role="option" ng-repeat="item in $select.items" ng-if="$select.open" ng-click="$select.select(item,$select.skipFocusser,$event)" id="ui-select-choices-row-4-3"><span class="ui-select-choices-row-inner" uis-transclude-append="">
                            <span ng-bind-html="item.nombre | highlight: $select.search" class="ng-binding ng-scope">ALTO DEL CARMEN</span>
                        
                        </span></div><!-- end ngIf: $select.open --><!-- end ngRepeat: item in $select.items --></li></ul><div class="ui-select-no-choice"></div><ui-select-single></ui-select-single><input ng-disabled="$select.disabled" class="ui-select-focusser ui-select-offscreen ng-scope" type="text" id="focusser-4" aria-label="Select box focus" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" disabled=""></div>
                </td>
                
        </tr>
```

Comment: Esto es....??? Una pregunta??? Si es así tienes que [formularla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) aquí, en la sección de respuestas, no obtendrás ayuda

Comment: No añadas las ediciones a tu pregunta en la parte de respuestas. Edita eso para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Ya te dijeron que tienes que [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/479267/edit) tu pregunta